# GIT: Not showing files I have push to the repository

Tags: git, github, git-push, git-fork

I have fork a repo and pull:

```
git pull origin master
```

I add some files and made some changes and I want to push my changes to my fork:

```
git add -A
git commit -m "some changes"
git push
```

But I got this error:

```
fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin master
```

I tried to set the origin:

```
git push origin master
```

But I got this error:

```
error: src refspec develop does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/meme/forkRepo.git'
```

I fixed with this:

git checkout master

and finally I made a push:

```
git push
Everything up-to-date
```

But I went to GitHub and check my fork repo in the browser but the files I add and the files changes are not not showing. Any of you knows where did my changes went?, I still can see the files and my changes on my computer.

I really appreciate you help

Comment: Your `push` didn't really push anything. Are you sure that you committed a change before trying to push it? The `src refspec dev does not match any` mean that you try to push a branch which does not yet exist even locally. It looks like you were on `dev`, did not commit anything and tried to push.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the current branch doesn't exist in upstream for some reason. Notice in the error message it tells you exactly what to use, but you missed the `--set-upstream` flag.

> But I got this error:
>
> fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch. To push the
>   current branch and set the remote as upstream, use
>
> ```
> git push --set-upstream origin master I tried to set the origin:
> ```
>
> git push origin master

Do

```
git push --set-upstream origin master
```

Comment: I faced the same issue. Tried setting the upstream, although it doesn't work.

`$ git push --set-upstream origin branchname`
`Everything up-to-date`
`Branch 'branchname' set up to track remote branch 'branchname' from 'origin'.`

`$ git push`
`Everything up-to-date`
But then again, when I went to my repo, I am unable to see the changes I have pushed.  
  
Would be great, if you could help me out!